# Epson pp-100II Printer sending an ISO file to the printer using JDF

Tags: printer, iso-image, compact-disc, burning, epson-workforce

I am currently trying to burn an ISO file to a CD using an Epson pp-100II Printer/Burner.  I an trying to utalize the TDBridge and send a Job Discription File(JDF) and give it a Format type of ISO9660L2.

JDF Example

```
PUBLISHER=Publisher 0
COPIES=1
DISC_TYPE=CD
FORMAT=ISO9660L2
DATA=C:\iso\someFile.iso
LABEL=C:\Temp\someFile.tdd
JOB_ID=20171128162645845
```

When sending this file to the printer folder the status comes back as

```
[ACTIVE_JOB]
[COMPLETE_JOB]
JOB1=20171128162645845
[20171128162645845]
STATUS=6
ERROR=JDF0902
DETAIL_STATUS=14
```

This error when looking it up comes out to be:

```
JDF0902 The specified directory path (including the file name) does
not conform to the specified disc format.
```

I have the ability to mount the original ISO and it works fine.  I have also tried burning it as UDF102 and that worked fine but I had to mount the ISO after I put the CD in the drive.  I need to get the .iso file to burn to the CD as type ISO9660L2 or some comparable format where I don't have to mount the contents of the CD when i put it into a computer.  Any point in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify where the printer fits in the workflow of burning an ISO to the CD?

Comment: The TDBridge from Epson is using the Job Description File to send to the Printer/Burner.  I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the JDF or with the printer configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the Data that I wanted to burn was really an IMAGE.  I needed to replace the DATA= to IMAGE= in the JDF.

```
PUBLISHER=Publisher 0
COPIES=1
DISC_TYPE=CD
FORMAT=ISO9660L2
IMAGE=C:\iso\someFile.iso
LABEL=C:\Temp\someFile.tdd
JOB_ID=20171128162645845
```